# I want to use icons on my page, for only 10 icons should I download the icons or use a CDN?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, cdn

I want to use about `10-15` icons on my website. Should I use `CDN` or download all of the icons separately?
Which will be more fast `CDN` or using separately and what should be preferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very difficult to answer this as it requires more information about the size of the icons you want to use, the size of the full icon set, your websites host transfer speeds and the speeds of the CDN.

Best way for you to make a call is to test it yourself, include the 15 icons and use the Network tab in Developer tools to see how much time it takes to load the icons. Then switch to the CDN and check that. Best to do each test around 20 times on different connection speeds to get a good enough average.

But remember, one of the main benefits of using a CDN is that *hopefully* the user will have already come across the files and have them cached, which means they won't have to go through a HTTP transfer.

My particular answer would be go with the CDN unless the difference in size is large.

Comment: +1 Agreed and I'd add that you have to consider load. Your server (hosting the images) might respond quickly, even comparable to the CDN, if the number of requests is low. But if you get a burst of users, the CDN will likely have a much higher tolerance before its performance is affected.